# Redirect Site Geologically

Tags: multisite, redirect

I am using WordPress mu and need to redirect my site based on the users geo location.

For example if you go to yahoo from the US it will goes to yahoo.com, but if you visit the site from India it goes to in.yahoo.com or in the UK to uk.yahoo.com, etc.

Is there a way to have my WordPress do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geographical-redirect/

Alternatively, roll your own, using any GeoIP service (MaxMind for example, or get your own GeoIP database) and use [`wp_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) based on the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I'm about to implement a similar thing and wondered why no-one here or on many other posts have considered PHP's GeoIP functions? http://us1.php.net/geoip - It appears you can use this without an external IP DB, etc.

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/geoip.setup.php you still need Maxmind's Geo database. The question isn't really about geolocation as it is about doing a redirect based on IP address in WordPress.